# pipe process output to command split by line and whitespace

Tags: pipe, xargs, cut, split

On the system I'm using I often need to cancel jobs I run. I can check my jobs like this:

```
$ showq|grep jquick
2001744              jquick    Running   120    00:08:26  Mon Apr 11 11:06:02
2002020              jquick    Running   120    00:22:04  Mon Apr 11 11:19:40
2003328              jquick    Running   240     1:43:34  Mon Apr 11 12:41:10
2006300              jquick    Running   120     4:59:16  Mon Apr 11 15:56:52
2006312              jquick    Running   120     4:59:16  Mon Apr 11 15:56:52
```

What I do now is cancel each job ID manually: `$ canceljob 2001744 2002020 2003328 2006300 2006312`.

How can I filter this output to directly pipe the job IDs to `canceljob`?

Comment: Does `qselect -u jquick` give you output that's easier to use?

Comment: Yes. Thanks - I didn't know I could do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
showq | awk '/jquick/ { printf "canceljob %d\n",$1}'
```

if OK, pipe to bash, or

```
 showq | awk '/jquick/ { print $1}' | xargs canceljob
```

Answer (score 3):

Parsing whitespace-delimited columns is something awk does well.

```
canceljob $(showq | awk '$2 == "jquick" {print $1}')
```

or more directly

```
showq | awk '$2 == "jquick" {system("canceljob " + $1)}'
```

Alternatively, pass a constraint to [`showq`](http://docs.adaptivecomputing.com/maui/commands/showq.php) to make it report only the desired jobs.

```
canceljob $(showq -w user=jquick)
```